# Removing an element just before window.open(url)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to remove a div from a page and right after it to open a url in a new tab.
What happens is, when I get back to the page where the div was, I see the div that was supposed to be removed for about half a second.

Is there a way to solve this?

Using a timer won't help because it would cut the synchronous call to window.open and the browser won't allow it since it didn't origin from a user click.

Thanks,
Shaul.

Comment: Start hidden as default?

Comment: add a class to the div as you run the window.open, better have a callback function for opening the window after hiding the div is executed.

Comment: Starting hidden as default won't help. I don't want the the div hidden. I want it to hide only when I open the new tab. Using a callback for opening is not synchronous and the browser won't recognize it as a click that originated from the user. The code is something like: div.remove; window.open(url, _blank)

Answer (score 0):

Call this function will hide your div and open your link in a new tab. Hope this is what you wanted.

```
function openNewTab(){
    setTimeout(function() { window.open("http://www.google.com"); }, 2000);
    $('#mydiv').hide();
}
```